# mysql (innodb) select distinct + calculate values to copy in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to combine some queries to (eventually) use them in a stored procedure because I'm afraid in the long run it will take some time to process due to calculating and I guess a datawarehouse makes faster lookups possible.

I came up with this, but I keep getting syntax error messages (#1064) *(check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select distinct)*
Does anyone know a nice aproach for this?

```
insert into datawarehouse (itemid,rating) values
(select distinct itemid from ratings),
(select sum(rating)/count(*)from ratings where itemid in (select distinct itemid from ratings))
```

If I run the inner select queries separately it works but combining it seems troublesome.

In a nutshell I want to retrieve (i) the distinct itemid from table ratings, (ii) perform some calculations on the rows of table ratings for each itemid
and copy those into table datawarehouse.

If anyone has an idea or a good read on this, I would love to hear it.

Comment: In SQL Server, and I believe MySql, you need to use INSERT INTO SELECT rather than INSERT INTO VALUES. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) and [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
INSERT INTO datawarehouse (itemid, rating) SELECT itemid, sum(rating)/count(*) FROM ratings GROUP BY itemid
```

Comment: that worked superb! Thank you. Just wondering about two things. how would one do this with for instance with multiple source tables; perhaps using union? Is the "group by itemid" obligatory to pair the rating with the itemid?

Comment: You use group by when you want to aggregate something, in this case you want to sum all ratings and count them for each itemid, thus GROUP BY itemid.  If you have multiple tables that you can relate to each other you can JOIN them and then perform your select.

Comment: thanks im going to play with it around and read some more. With aggregate you mean pairing the values properly right?

Comment: "pairing" is probably not the best word choice. I'd rather say... group :). When you use GROUP BY(field) you get 1 record for each distinct value of "field" you have got. Say you have a table named "People" containing name, surname and city where people live. If you want to know how many people live in each city you use COUNT(*) and GROUP BY(city), thus counting the number of people for each city.